# Vim's use of tab autocomplete (bash-completion) does not display symlinks

Tags: vim, bash-completion, neovim

I'm using Neovim on a Mac.  My tab completion function works as expected in both  `zsh` (my default) and `bash`.  Vim also opens symlinks from the terminal. 
 However, when the function is invoked within Vim `:e[dit]` the search result *excludes* the symlinks. I would expect the results to *include* the symlinks. I'm at a loss to figure out what's going on.

Note: despite my mentioning `zsh`, Vim seems to be invoking `bash-completion`.

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `$ vim <tab>` in your shell, Vim is not running so it's not doing anything or invoking anything. In your shell, tab-completion is *entirely* handled by your shell.

In Vim, tab-completion in the command-line is entirely handled by Vim so there's no reason to expect it to use whatever you are using in your shell.

And both `:edit` and command-line completion are perfectly capable of handling symlinks.

But… Vim or Neovim? Bash or zsh? And what "function" are you talking about exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  To clarify: My only issue is with the options generated when I hit `<tab>` within Vim `:e[dit]`.   The list of options does not display symlinks... :-/

Comment: Well it does, here, with `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

Comment: When you're right, you're right.  This is helpful.  It could be a setting in my `.vimrc`, but I think I should start with the `plugins`.  Do you know of an efficient way to systematically test each of my plugins without changing the `.vimrc` file but rather starting with `-Nu NONE`.

Answer (score 0):

Over time (a.k.a. subsequent updates) the problem was fixed.  To close out on the question I have the following to report that I hope will help:

1. We identified that the problem was associated with my unique state of my nvim; disabling plugins "fixed" the problem
2. The documentation for the vim feature can be found using `:help cmdline-completion`
3. The specific feature that was not behaving as expected is called `file name completion`
4. The documentation *does not* provide a description of how to adjust the behavior of this feature such as whether or not to show symlinks
5. The documentation *does* describe how we need to `set noncompatible` to enable the `cmdline-completion` using `<tab>`
6. Other sources suggest that the feature is enabled by the underlying shell; that idea was not endorsed in the answer provided earlier.

Conclusion: The most likely solution would have been to disable a plugin.  This is not a great end for the effort required to work through the 20+ plugins.  As "randomly" as it came to be, it also went away.  Other than making sure I increased my understanding of how vim works, I believe there was not much more that could be done.